# How to implement FlinkKafkaProducer serializer for Kafka 2.2

Tags: java, apache-kafka, apache-flink

I've been working on updating a Flink processor (Flink version 1.9) that reads from Kafka and then writes to Kafka. We have written this processor to run towards a Kafka 0.10.2 cluster and now we have deployed a new Kafka cluster running version 2.2. Therefore I set out to update the processor to use the latest FlinkKafkaConsumer and FlinkKafkaProducer (as suggested by the Flink docs). However I've run into some problems with the Kafka producer. I'm unable to get it to Serialize data using deprecated constructors (not surprising) and I've been unable to find any implementations or examples online about how to implement a Serializer (all the examples are using older Kafka Connectors)

The current implementation (for Kafka 0.10.2) is as follows

```
FlinkKafkaProducer010<String> eventBatchFlinkKafkaProducer = new FlinkKafkaProducer010<String>(
                "playerSessions",
                new SimpleStringSchema(),
                producerProps,
                (FlinkKafkaPartitioner) null
        );
```

When trying to implement the following FlinkKafkaProducer

```
FlinkKafkaProducer<String> eventBatchFlinkKafkaProducer = new FlinkKafkaProducer<String>(
                "playerSessions",
                new SimpleStringSchema(),
                producerProps,
                null
        );
```

I get the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.connectors.kafka.FlinkKafkaProducer.<init>(FlinkKafkaProducer.java:525)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.connectors.kafka.FlinkKafkaProducer.<init>(FlinkKafkaProducer.java:483)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.connectors.kafka.FlinkKafkaProducer.<init>(FlinkKafkaProducer.java:357)
    at com.ebs.flink.sessionprocessor.SessionProcessor.main(SessionProcessor.java:122)
```

and I haven't been able to figure out why.
The constructor for FlinkKafkaProducer is also deprecated and when I try implementing the non-deprecated constructor I can't figure out how to serialize the data.
The following is how it would look:

```
FlinkKafkaProducer<String> eventBatchFlinkKafkaProducer = new FlinkKafkaProducer<String>(
                "playerSessions",
                new KafkaSerializationSchema<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public ProducerRecord<byte[], byte[]> serialize(String s, @Nullable Long aLong) {
                        return null;
                    }
                },
                producerProps,
                FlinkKafkaProducer.Semantic.EXACTLY_ONCE
        );
```

But I don't understand how to implement the KafkaSerializationSchema and I find no examples of this online or in the Flink docs.

Does anyone have any experience implementing this or any tips on why the FlinkProducer gets NullPointerException in the  step?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you are just sending String to Kafka:

```
public class ProducerStringSerializationSchema implements KafkaSerializationSchema<String>{

    private String topic;   

    public ProducerStringSerializationSchema(String topic) {
        super();
        this.topic = topic;
    }

    @Override
    public ProducerRecord<byte[], byte[]> serialize(String element, Long timestamp) {
        return new ProducerRecord<byte[], byte[]>(topic, element.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
    }

}
```

For sending a Java Object:

```
import org.apache.flink.shaded.jackson2.com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonProcessingException;
import org.apache.flink.shaded.jackson2.com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import org.apache.flink.streaming.connectors.kafka.KafkaSerializationSchema;
import org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.ProducerRecord;


    public class ObjSerializationSchema implements KafkaSerializationSchema<MyPojo>{

        private String topic;   
        private ObjectMapper mapper;

        public ObjSerializationSchema(String topic) {
            super();
            this.topic = topic;
        }

        @Override
        public ProducerRecord<byte[], byte[]> serialize(MyPojo obj, Long timestamp) {
            byte[] b = null;
            if (mapper == null) {
                mapper = new ObjectMapper();
            }
             try {
                b= mapper.writeValueAsBytes(obj);
            } catch (JsonProcessingException e) {
                // TODO 
            }
            return new ProducerRecord<byte[], byte[]>(topic, b);
        }

    }
```

In your code

```
.addSink(new FlinkKafkaProducer<>(producerTopic, new ObjSerializationSchema(producerTopic), 
                        params.getProperties(), FlinkKafkaProducer.Semantic.EXACTLY_ONCE));
```

Comment: Thanks! Now I can run the processor without crashing. However this introduced another problem (unsure if it's related) but now I get **org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException: Timeout expired while initializing transactional state in 60000ms.** when starting the Flink processor (and it keeps retrying). Consuming works fine so I guess it's something with the producer.

Comment: Apparently the FlinkKafkaProducer.Semantic.EXACTLY_ONCE was the culprit, changing to AT_LEAST_ONCE removed the timeout. I'll need to dig in my config to see why. Thanks for a quick and perfect answer!

Comment: You need to set transaction.timeout.ms property to 1 hour -- see my answer to this question.

Comment: Why not pass `timestamp` into the ProducerRecord?

Comment: @cricket_007 Not passing the timestamp as my record doesn't have any timestamp associated with it. In this case `null` will be passed and the producer by default will assign the timestamp using `System.currentTimeMillis()`

Comment: @TimJosefsson As david mentioned you have to increase the `transaction.max.timeout.ms` if you are using  `EXACTLY_ONCE` semantic. Keep in mind that `AT_LEAST_ONCE` semantic may send duplicate records to kafka.

Comment: Semantic.EXACTLY_ONCE not working in my case Semantic.AT_LEAST_ONCE worked

Answer (score 2):

To the deal with the timeout in the case of FlinkKafkaProducer.Semantic.EXACTLY_ONCE you should read https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-stable/dev/connectors/kafka.html#kafka-011-and-newer, particularly this part:

> Semantic.EXACTLY_ONCE mode relies on the ability to commit transactions that were started before taking a checkpoint, after recovering from the said checkpoint. If the time between Flink application crash and completed restart is larger than Kafka’s transaction timeout there will be data loss (Kafka will automatically abort transactions that exceeded timeout time). Having this in mind, please configure your transaction timeout appropriately to your expected down times.
>
> Kafka brokers by default have transaction.max.timeout.ms set to 15 minutes. This property will not allow to set transaction timeouts for the producers larger than it’s value. FlinkKafkaProducer011 by default sets the transaction.timeout.ms property in producer config to 1 hour, thus transaction.max.timeout.ms should be increased before using the Semantic.EXACTLY_ONCE mode.