# Flink - serialize a pojo to Kafka sink

Tags: java, apache-kafka, apache-flink, flink-streaming

The structure of my Flink code is:
get data in with kafka (topic_1_in) -> deserialize messages -> map -> manipulate the data -> get a POJO -> serialize message -> send data out with kafka (topic_1_out)

I'm now on the last stage where I would like to serialize my POJO. I have found the following example on the Flink website:

```
DataStream<String> stream = ...

Properties properties = new Properties();
properties.setProperty("bootstrap.servers", "localhost:9092");

    FlinkKafkaProducer<String> myProducer = new FlinkKafkaProducer<>(
            "my-topic",                  // target topic
            new SimpleStringSchema(),    // serialization schema
            properties,                  // producer config
            FlinkKafkaProducer.Semantic.EXACTLY_ONCE); // fault-tolerance
    
    stream.addSink(myProducer);
```

But I don't understand how to implement a serialization schema.

I also read different possibilities:

https://flink.apache.org/news/2020/04/15/flink-serialization-tuning-vol-1.html

But still, I'm a bit confused on how to convert my POJO to a string to feed the Kafka sink. The class is really simple so I assume that is quite straightforward.

```
public class POJO_block {
            public Double id;
            public Double tr_p;
            public Integer size;
            public Double last_info;
            public Long millis_last;
            private ArrayList<Tuple3<Integer, Integer, Integer>> list_val;

}
```

Any example would be really appreciated.

thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [link](https://flink.apache.org/news/2020/04/15/flink-serialization-tuning-vol-1.html) mentioned in the question refers to internal Flink serialization, which is used when Flink needs to ship some of our data from one part of the cluster to another, though is not relevant when writing to Kafka.

When Flink is interacting with an external storage, like Kafka, it relies on a *connector*, and how serialization happens when doing so depends on the configuration details of that connector as well as specific mechanisms of the underlying external storage (e.g. concepts like *key* and *value* in the case of kafka records).

In the case you describe, because your program is using the DataStream API and is communicating with Kafka, the connector you're using is the Kafka Datastream API, and its documentation sits [here](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.12/dev/connectors/kafka.html#apache-kafka-connector).

In the code you provided, this parameter of the `FlinkKafkaProducer` sink specifies how the serialization happens:

```
// this is probably not what you want:
new SimpleStringSchema(),    // serialization schema
```

This configuration is not working because `SimpleStringSchema` is expecting strings as input, so a stream of `POJO_block` will make it fail.

You can pass instead any implementation of `org.apache.flink.streaming.connectors.kafka.KafkaSerializationSchema`, containing one main function, letting you define the byte value of both the kafka key and value corresponding to each `POJO_block` block instance (i.e. `T` below):

```
ProducerRecord<byte[], byte[]> serialize(T element, @Nullable Long timestamp);
```

Note that if you were using the Table API to read and write Kafka instead of the DataStream API, [this connector](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.12/dev/table/connectors/kafka.html) would be used instead, which has a convenient [format](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.12/dev/table/connectors/formats/) configuration with ready-to-use formats like csv, json, avro, Debezium...

Comment: Hi, could you please give me an example of an implementation of the KafkaSerializationSchema? And yes I'm using DataStream API.  thanks for the help.

Comment: Hi, I found this good example, (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58644549/how-to-implement-flinkkafkaproducer-serializer-for-kafka-2-2), but given the fact that I will be using the message in python I'm thinking of converting my POJO to string and then serialize it, instead of sending out a POJO and struggle in python to open it.

Comment: Hi, the example you found seems fairly good: the `b= mapper.writeValueAsBytes(obj);` line is actually serializing the pojo into json (as a `byte[]` since that's what Kafka requires, although those bytes are actually the UTF-8 encoding of a string) => I'm expecting that the python app is able to parse that without problem. If you want to double check quickly, you can also install the great kafkacat tool then print the content of Kafka on the linux command line with a simple `kafkacat -C -b localhost:9092 -t my-topic`, which should print the json version of `POJO_block` to stdout.

Comment: I didn't know about the Kafkacat this is quite cool! Thanks for the help, really appreciated. s