# In what binary format should I ingest Kafka topic to Druid, whose events are sent from FlinkKafkaProducer[<Scala case class>]?

Tags: scala, apache-kafka, apache-flink, flink-streaming, druid

I have a data pipeline, written in Scala, to improve.

- As-Is: Flink 1.8 -> (Tranquility, which officially supports Druid 0.9.2) -> Druid 0.20.1
- To-Be: Flink 1.11 -> Kafka -> Druid 0.20.1 using recommended [Druid Kafka Indexing Service](https://druid.apache.org/docs/0.20.1/development/extensions-core/kafka-ingestion.html).

The Flink app generates DataStream of Scala case class (ExampleData in the below code).

According to [Flink Serialization Tuning Vol. 1: Choosing your Serializer — if you can](https://flink.apache.org/news/2020/04/15/flink-serialization-tuning-vol-1.html), Scala case class falls into "**Flink-provided special serializers**", but I am not sure how it gets serialized and thus how (i.e. in what format) it is supposed to be deserialized when Druid reads it from Kafka topic.

(I don't want to add dependencies to Flink app unless for good reason, to keep maintenance cost less)

So my questions are

- Which (binary) data format mentioned in [the Druid doc](https://druid.apache.org/docs/0.20.1/ingestion/data-formats.html) should I use for Druid to ingest events from Kafka topic?
- Or how can I specify data format on Flink side so Druid can read (via Kafka)?
- With regards to data format, is there any setting required on Kafka side as well?

I appreciate all the help/info you will be providing, thank you for your attention.

### Code

#### Scala case class

```
case class ExampleData(timestamp: Long, id: Int, name: String, price: BigDecimal) extends BaseData

trait BaseData {
    val timestamp: Long
    val name: String
}
```

#### Flink -> Kafka

```
val props: ParameterTool = ...
...
KafkaSink.sendToKafka(exampleDataStream, props)
```

```
object KafkaSink {
  def sendToKafka(exampleDataStream: DataStream[ExampleData], props: ParameterTool): DataStreamSink[ExampleData] = {
    val topic: String = ...
    val properties: Properties = ... 

    val producer = new FlinkKafkaProducer[ExampleData](
      topic,
      new ExampleDataSerializationSchema(topic),
      properties,
      FlinkKafkaProducer.Semantic.EXACTLY_ONCE)

    exampleDataStream.addSink(producer)
  }
}
```

```
import org.apache.flink.shaded.jackson2.com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonProcessingException
import org.apache.flink.shaded.jackson2.com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper

class ExampleDataSerializationSchema(topic: String) extends KafkaSerializationSchema[ExampleData]{
  val mapper = new ObjectMapper()

  // https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.11/dev/connectors/kafka.html#the-serializationschema
  // https://stackoverflow.com/a/58644689
  override def serialize(element: ExampleData, timestamp: java.lang.Long): ProducerRecord[Array[Byte], Array[Byte]] = {
    val elementAsBytes: Array[Byte] =
      try {
        mapper.writeValueAsBytes(element)
      } catch {
        case e: JsonProcessingException => {
          Array[Byte]()
        }
      }
    new ProducerRecord[Array[Byte], Array[Byte]](topic, elementAsBytes)
    }
}
```

### Environment

- Druid 0.20.1   (can upgrade a bit more if absolutely needed)
- Flink 1.11.2   (should be 1.11.x due to some reason)
- Kafka 0.11.x (we don't have much control on version)

### References

- https://druid.apache.org/docs/0.20.1/development/extensions-core/kafka-ingestion.html
- https://flink.apache.org/news/2020/04/15/flink-serialization-tuning-vol-1.html
- https://druid.apache.org/docs/0.20.1/ingestion/data-formats.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your serializer uses Jackson/JSON, doesn't matter that it is a Scala class, so you should use Driud's JSON one

```
  "ioConfig": {
    "topic": "your_topic_name",
    "inputFormat": {
      "type": "json"
    },
```

FWIW, if you add Confluent Schema Registry to your environment, you do not need to write your own SerializationSchema for each class, as you can use `ConfluentRegistryAvroSerializationSchema` (Avro format), and Druid seems to support the Schema Registry as well (at least for Avro, not sure about Protobuf or JSONSchema).

Comment: Thank you! Glad I don't need to add dependencies.

Let me try the solution to see if it works in my case. I do see the below error and I think I need to check the log as well as Druid supervisor spec config.

`2021-08-06T04:00:32,288 ERROR [MonitorScheduler-0] org.apache.druid.indexing.common.stats.TaskRealtimeMetricsMonitor - [224,635] unparseable events discarded. Turn on debug logging to see exception stack trace.`

Comment: Error seems to suggest that your parser spec doesn't match the incoming messages

Comment: I saw kafka console consumer output empty JSON, and wonder if it is a de/serialization issue with Jackson? https://stackoverflow.com/q/68734697/9728653

Comment: I don't see in your question where you ever created a `ExampleData` object that is being sent, but you should log the `JsonProcessingException` and probably return null there rather than an empty array, or define `elementAsBytes: Try[Array[Byte]]`. If you want to serialize Scala case classes, refer to https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-module-scala